# inserting data into database table via hibernate mapping fails

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, mapping

I am using Hibernate to insert a row into a database, I am using Visual Paradigm (Enterprise Edition) to generate database tables.

Here are the errors

> org.orm.PersistentException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException:
>   not-null property references a null or transient value:
>   com.patientmanagement.model.Patient.visitRecord   at
>   org.orm.PersistentSession.saveOrUpdate(PersistentSession.java:631)    at
>   org.orm.PersistentManager.saveObject(PersistentManager.java:287)  at
>   com.patientmanagement.model.PatientDAO.save(PatientDAO.java:303)  at
>   com.test.InsertData.main(InsertData.java:28) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a
>   null or transient value:
>   com.patientmanagement.model.Patient.visitRecord   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:100)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:312)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:687)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:679)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:675)
>     at org.orm.PersistentSession.saveOrUpdate(PersistentSession.java:629)
>     ... 3 more

And here is the Insert function to test

```
public class InsertData {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws PersistentException
    {
        PersistentTransaction trans=PatientmanagementPersistentManager.instance().getSession().beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            //create patient instance
            Patient patient=PatientDAO.createPatient();

            //set patients properties
            patient.setName("Markus Rosevelt");
            patient.setRegisterDate(new Date());

            //save patient
            PatientDAO.save(patient);
            trans.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            trans.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have defined the column visitRecord as NOT NULL on your database and now you are trying to insert a null value on that column, or your mapping is not correct, can you show your mapping and your table definition?

Answer (score 0):

This message means that you cannot create a Patient entity with an empty property.  The empty property in this case is the visitRecord property within the Patient entity.  You can assign a value to this property using something like

```
patient.setVisitRecord(some values);
```

I hope this solves your problem.